# How can I achieve a binding path which is bound by another binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm writing my own UserControl which displays data in a ListBox. I want to achieve something similar to a property like "DisplayMemberPath". In my example, it's "EditableMemberPath", which should determine which member will be displayed in the textbox. However, using a binding on a binding does not work.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, ElementName=me}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=me}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={Binding Path=ItemToImageConverter, ElementName=me}}" />

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path={Binding Path=EditableMemberPath, ElementName=me}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Can you help me finding a proper solution?

Best Regards
Oliver Hanappi

Comment: I've posted code that answers this question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777991/how-do-i-bind-the-binding-path-property-to-underlying-data/778146#778146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly in XAML (at least not with the built-in classes) : a `Binding` is not a `DependencyObject`, so you can't bind its properties.

However the post mentioned by Martin Harris looks promising...